# Python counting occurrences across multiple lines using loops

Tags: python

I want a quick pythonic method to give me a count in a loop. I am actually too embarrassed to post up my solutions which are currently not working.

Given a sample from a text file structured follows:

`script7
BLANK INTERRUPTION
script2
launch4.VBS
script3
script8
launch3.VBS
script5
launch1.VBS
script6`

I want a count of all times script[y] is followed by a launch[X]. Launch has a range of values from 1-5, whilst script has range of 1-15.

Using script3 as an example, I would need a count for each of the following in a given file:

```
script3
launch1
#count this

script3
launch2
#count this

script3
launch3
#count this

script3
launch4
#count this

script3
launch4
#count this

script3
launch5
#count this
```

I think the sheer number of loops involved here has surpassed my knowledge of Python. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example of the output your trying to achieve.

Comment: Without any code, and without a description of expected output, this question is off topic and could be closed. You did not even say if you want a separate count per script or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a multi-line regex - then the script becomes:

```
import re

# read all the text of the file, and clean it up
with open('counts.txt', 'rt') as f:
    alltext = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in f)

# find all occurrences of the script line followed by the launch line
cont = re.findall('^script(\d)\nlaunch(\d+)\.VBS\n(?mi)',alltext)

# accumulate the counts of each launch number for each script number
# into nested dictionaries
scriptcounts = {}
for scriptnum,launchnum in cont:
    # if we haven't seen this scriptnumber before, create the dictionary for it
    if scriptnum not in scriptcounts:
        scriptcounts[scriptnum]={}
    # if we haven't seen this launchnumber with this scriptnumber before,
    # initialize count to 0
    if launchnum not in scriptcounts[scriptnum]:
        scriptcounts[scriptnum][launchnum] = 0
    # incremement the count for this combination of script and launch number
    scriptcounts[scriptnum][launchnum] += 1

# produce the output in order of increasing scriptnum/launchnum
for scriptnum in sorted(scriptcounts.keys()):
    for launchnum in sorted(scriptcounts[scriptnum].keys()):
        print "script%s\nlaunch%s.VBS\n# count %d\n"%(scriptnum,launchnum,scriptcounts[scriptnum][launchnum])
```

The output (in the format you requested) is, for example:

```
script2
launch1.VBS
# count 1

script2
launch4.VBS
# count 1

script5
launch1.VBS
# count 1

script8
launch3.VBS
# count 3
```

re.findall() returns a list of all the matches - each match is a list of the  () parts of the pattern except the (?mi) which is a directive to tell the regular expression matcher to work across line ends \n and to match case insensitive. The regex pattern as it stands e.g. fragment 'script(\d)' pulls out the digit following the script/launch into the match - this could as easily include 'script' by being '(script\d)', similarly '(launch\d+\.VBS)' and only the printing would need modification to handle this variation.

HTH
barny

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which uses nested dictionaries. Please tell me if you would like the output to be in a different format:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import re
script_dict={}
with open('infile.txt','r') as infile:
    scriptre = re.compile(r"^script\d+$")
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if scriptre.match(line) is not None:
            script_dict[line] = {}

    infile.seek(0) # go to beginning
    launchre = re.compile(r"^launch\d+\.[vV][bB][sS]$")
    current=None
    for line in infile:
        line = line.rstrip()
        if line in script_dict:
            current=line
        elif launchre.match(line) is not None and current is not None:
            if line not in script_dict[current]:
                script_dict[current][line] = 1 
            else:
                script_dict[current][line] += 1

print(script_dict)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution using defaultdict with Counters and [regex with lookahead](https://regex101.com/r/cT0pC8/1).

```
import re
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

with open('in.txt', 'r') as f:
    # make sure we have only \n as lineend and no leading or trailing whitespaces
    # this makes the regex less complex
    alltext = '\n'.join(line.strip() for line in f)

# find keyword script\d+ and capture it, then lazy expand and capture everything
# with lookahead so that we stop as soon as and only if next word is 'script' or
# end of the string
scriptPattern = re.compile(r'(script\d+)(.*?)(?=script|\n?$)', re.DOTALL)

# just find everything that matches launch\d+
launchPattern = re.compile(r'launch\d+')

# create a defaultdict with a counter for every entry
scriptDict = defaultdict(Counter)

# go through all matches
for match in scriptPattern.finditer(alltext):
    script, body = match.groups()
    # update the counter of this script
    scriptDict[script].update(launchPattern.findall(body))

# print the results
for script in sorted(scriptDict):
    counter = scriptDict[script]
    if len(counter):
        print('{} launches:'.format(script))
        for launch in sorted(counter):
            count = counter[launch]
            print('\t{} {} time(s)'.format(launch, count))
    else:
        print('{} launches nothing'.format(script))
```

Using the string on regex101 (see link above) I get the following result:

```
script2 launches:
    launch4 1 time(s)
script3 launches nothing
script5 launches:
    launch1 1 time(s)
script6 launches nothing
script7 launches nothing
script8 launches:
    launch3 1 time(s)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `setdefault` method

**code:**

```
dic={}
with open("a.txt") as inp:
    check=0
    key_string=""
    for line in inp:
        if check:
            if line.strip().startswith("launch") and int(line.strip()[6])<6:
                print "yes"
                dic[key_string]=dic.setdefault(key_string,0)+1
            check=0
        if line.strip().startswith("script"):
            key_string=line.strip()
            check=1
```

For your given input the output would be

**output:**

```
{"script3":6}
```